# removing improper html tags using jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, radgrid

I am using a listview embedded inside a radgrid.
Its working fine on local environment, but when i uploaded the page into sharepoint server, page is rendering with some improper tags like

```
"</td/>" and "</tr/>"
```

How can i remove this tags using Jquery ?

Adding image for more clarity

[image]

**More Code:**

```
<telerik:radgrid id="RadGrd" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false" clientsettings-allowexpandcollapse="true" allowpaging="false">
<mastertableview tablelayout="Fixed" cssclass="userData" cellspacing="2">
        <FooterStyle CssClass="subRowTop" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="subRowTop" />
        <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="subRowTop" />
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <!-- 7 more grid template column -->
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <tbody runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder">
                            </tbody>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr class="odd hide">
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td >
                                </td>
                                <td >
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
</mastertableview>
```

The intention to use list view inside telerik column for to show drill down data

Comment: Fixing the problem itself isn't the way to go, especially with jQuery. In this case, you need to fix the _root cause_ of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these unexpected html tags are coming between two tr's having class odd and subRowTop respectively and subRowTop comes first, i iterated from these row and removed this unnecessary tags

```
$('.subRowTop').each(function () {
                    var currentRow = $(this);
                    while (true) {
                        if (currentRow.next('tr.odd').length > 0) {
                            currentRow = currentRow.next('tr.odd');
                        }
                        else {
                            currentRow.nextUntil('tr').remove();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
```